# Moving documents

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a document that I want updated by an employee every week. Now I have figured out how to copy the document using a list workflow by changing the status of the document to completed, where it is then copied to "Archived documents' library and deleted from "Documents' library. because it is a weekly operation I would prefer to have the document moved to archive and replaced with a blank copy each week. so I had created a library to store a blank document, and attempted to create a flow to copy this into documents but it wont work because it is triggered by the completion of the document and when a document is marked as completed it is moved to archive instantly so it is like there is nothing there to trigger the flow to move the blank document to document. 
how can I adjust this to work? Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

One option could perhaps be to revert the document to a prior version rather than deleting it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean being that I am a new user of sharepoint. How do you revert a document ?

Comment: This is a good primer : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-1555d642-23ee-446a-990a-bcab618c7a37